# How can we translate code generated by appium to use it with protractor?

Tags: html, css, jasmine, protractor, appium

Is there a method that we can translate directly code generated by Appium to use it with Protractor?

I find myself always obliged to rewrite code from HTML to search element by class or by CSS because the code generated by Appium recorder used in Protractor tells me that no element found.

Here The details of Appium Inspector for `show menu button` for example:

[image: screenshot of Appium Inspector]

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div flex="" class="flex">
    <button class="menu md-button show-sm md-ink-ripple hide" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="toggleSideMenu()" aria-label="Show Menu" hide="" show-sm="">
        <ng-md-icon icon="menu" class="ng-scope">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
                <path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2z"></path>
                <path d="M3 13h18v-2H3v2z"></path>
                <path d="M3 6v2h18V6H3z"></path>
            </svg>
        </ng-md-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please improve the question formatting to make it readable

Comment: I updated it a little bit, shall i reduce the html code to make it just on the show menu button?

Comment: its too long, could you cut it short to minimum useful block

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestion. It's done